# NHibernate: mapping a reference

Tags: nhibernate, join, mapping

In essence I am trying to do the following with NHibernate (trying to make it understandable):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM ChildTable c
INNER JOIN ParentTable p ON p.Id = c.ParentId AND p.Language = :language
```

And I want `p.*` of course as a property of type `ParentObject` in the `ChildObject`.

The ChildTable does not have a Language column. So :language is taken as a constant from the program.

I was thinking about creating a UserType that converts from the c.ParentId to the ParentObject and back again (conversion dependent on :language).

Is that possible?

I already did a simple IntToString IUserType for something else.

Would I just do a normal `session.Get<ParentClass>(idLangIndexObject)`  in the `NullSafeGet` method then or would that have implications in any of the `IUserType` internals?

I tried doing `ApplyFilter()` on the `ParentClassMapping` too (trying to cut down only to one :language), but `References()` uses Get internally it seems, and Get ignores `ApplyFilter()`

Any other more elegant ideas?

There has got to be some way, this is not rocket science after all.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship from child to parent (not many-to-one), since each child can apparently have multiple parents. Map it as a collection to properly reflect this, and the collection load will take filters into account.